# `Overflow: hidden` is not working on browser re-sizing

Tags: html, css

`Overflow: hidden` is not working on browser re-sizing.

```
body {
  background-color: $body-color;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

When my application loads there is no scroll-bar, the moment i re-size the browser to mobile resolution the scroll-bar appears and from there it always stays. Is there anyway to make scrollbar hidden across all different resolution and sizes.

Comment: may be the scroll bar is appearing to other container instead of body. because once you give `overflow: hidden`, that element will not show scroll bar.

Comment: Bit vague providing more of your code would help us, or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

do you mean this?

an jsfiddle would be great..

Answer (score 0):

try putting your whole `body` in a wrapper then set the wrappers style like this

```
    #id_of_wrapper{
           overflow:hidden;
     }
```